# Javascript RegExp passwd validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have password constraints that i would like to validate:

- minimum length = 6
- upper case and lower case characters allowed
- at least 1 character (upper- or lowercase)
- at least 1 digit
- allowed special characters: _$#%&!?-.

Currently my regex looks like this:

```
/^(?=.*\d+)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z\_\$\#\%\&!\?\-\.]{6,}$/
```

Except for the special characters, all requirements are met. Can anybody explain to me what i am doing wrong with the special characters? As you can see, every character is escaped and grouped into a "allowed" character class. However, the test still fails.

thank you

Comment: Can you give us an example of a test that fails?  The regex looks fine to me.

Comment: Sure, using the following passwd the test fails in my app: asdfgH12&

Comment: The regex is OK (but can be simplified to `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[\w$#%&!?.-]{6,}$/i`). The problem must be somewhere else. How are you using the regex?

Comment: Thanks for your modification Tim! I am using the regex for validating a Sencha Touch 2.0 model (which uses the following implementation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with that password? It's more than 6 characters long, has at least one character, has at least one digit, and its special character is valid. It _should_ be returning true!

Comment: @SperanskyDanil that is really strange. Keeps on failing on my side

Comment: @all - i am an idiot. after looking at this regex for nearly an hour, i missed another validation a few lines above. It was a "safeString" validation that was originally used for filtering XSS related user input! I am sorry! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^(?=.{6})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[\w$#%&!?.-]+$/
```

or

```
/^(?=.{6})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[\w$#%&!?.-]+$/i
```